# Eliminate perceived index value from data frame concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate two data frames and write said data-frame to an excel file. The concatenation is performed somewhat successfully, but I'm having a difficult time eliminating the index row that also gets appended.

I would appreciate it if someone could highlight what it is I'm doing wrong. I thought providing the `"index = False"` argument at every excel call would eliminate the issue, but it has not. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOjuL.png)

Hopefully you can see the image, if not please let me know.

```
# filenames
file_name = "C:\\Users\\ga395e\\Desktop\\TEST_FILE.xlsx"
file_name2 = "C:\\Users\\ga395e\\Desktop\\TEST_FILE_2.xlsx"
#create data frames
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index = False)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_name2,index =False)

#filter frame
df3 = df2[['WDDT', 'Part Name', 'Remove SN']]

#concatenate values
df4 = df3['WDDT'].map(str)  + '-' +df3['Part Name'].map(str) + '-' + 'SN:'+ df3['Remove SN'].map(str)


test=pd.DataFrame(df4)
test=test.transpose()


df = pd.concat([df, test], axis=1)

df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\ga395e\\Desktop\\c.xlsx", index=False)
```

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the image i dont see the index. are you talking about the first row?

Comment: reset index on df and test before concat and play with drop=False or drop=True to see the difference.

Comment: yes, he talks about the index before T which becomes first row after T

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

so as the other users also wrote I dont see the index in your image as well because in this case you would have an output which would be like the following:

```
| Index | Column1  | Column2  |
|-------+----------+----------|
|     0 | Entry1_1 | Entry1_2 |
|     1 | Entry2_1 | Entry2_2 |
|     2 | Entry3_1 | Entry3_2 |
```

if you pass the `index=False` option the index will be removed:

```
 | Column1  | Column2  |
 |----------+----------|
 | Entry1_1 | Entry1_2 |
 | Entry2_1 | Entry2_2 |
 | Entry3_1 | Entry3_2 |
 |          |          |
```

which looks like it your case. Your problem be could related to the concatenation and the transposed matrix.

- Did you check here you temporary dataframe before exporting it?
- You might want to check if pandas imports the time column as a [time index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)
- if you want to delete those time columns you could use `df.drop` and pass an array of columns into this function, e.g. with `df.drop(df.columns[:3])`. Does this maybe solve your problem?